# Django template nested include passing variables

Tags: django, django-templates, django-3.2

I use django template `index.html` to render the frontpage. It includes another template to create a link icon. This template `url_icon.html` includes another template `icon.html`. When passing the arguments down the way, I face with an error. How to fix it?

index.html

```
.
.
.
{% include "url_icon.html" with name="return" url="/" %}
.
.
.
```

url_icon.html

```
<a href="{{url}}">{% include "icon.html" with icon={{ name }} %}</a>
```

icon.html

```
<img src="/static/images/{{ name }}.png" />
```

Causing an error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{'
```

[image: django-error]

Comment: isn't it just <a href="{{ url }}">{% include "icon.html" with icon=name %}</a>

Comment: @JimmyPells, it fixed my problem. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like there are a few things you can do to improve/fix this. Addressing #1 and #2 should fix your issue. I've also added suggestions for best practices that would probably require refactoring (#3, #4).

1. It looks like you need to remove the curly-braces from `name` inside the `{% include %}` tag. Context variables can be used inside tags without extra syntax.

url_icon.html:

```
{% include "icon.html" with icon=name %}
```

2. icon.html will have access to `name` since you're not using the `only` keyword when updating its context, so your code might appear to work at first ([{% include %} documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include)). However, it looks like your intention is to refer to it as `icon`.

- Use the variable `icon` in instead of `name`

icon.html:

```
<img src="/static/images/{{ icon }}.png" />
```

3. Optional suggestion: Use Django's staticfiles system

Try using the [`{% static %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#static) tag for your icon. This will help make deployment easier, especially if you use a separate CDN from your webserver. There's lots of literature on how to set up staticfiles for Django projects in production, it's a large topic, but you'll be able to approach it more easily if you use the `{% static %}` tag from the beginning.

4. Optional suggestion: Django's URL routing system

Your route in `index.html` is hard-coded to be `"/"`. Django has a powerful URL referencing system to leverage. If you've defined the root URL `/` using Django too, you can refer to it by name. [Docs: {% url %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url), and for the back-end, [reverse()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse).